Can I reference key name in dict value definition?
Is there a way to reference name of key at definition time of the value of the key? For example:
cmds = {"DO1": get_data(key), "DO2": get_data(key), ...}

If it is available each key will be substituted "DO1", "DO2", ...:
print(cmds)
{"DO1": get_data("DO1"), "DO2": get_data("DO2"), ...}

How do I achieve this idea? I want to save any function call to dictionary, even conditions.

Not in that syntax, but why not e.g. {key: get_data(key) for key in ...}?

"even conditions": which conditions? "any function call": but your example gives one function (get_data) for all keys. Is that not your scenario?

@jonrsharpe I thought that way first, but here's 4 patterns. So I thinking about it for other good or efficient way.

If I could customize this code, I wanted to add simple conditions like value == "1".
But in this content, I didn't mention, because that is not main question in my opinion.

@simryang your each command have each different work to do, so for each you have to create a different function, and have to call the function based on the cmd it is.

Also, you can just type the string twice. There are scenarios where simply "DO1": get_data("DO1") is better option than trying to be 100% DRY at all cost.

@Jeyekomon If the time comes for me to give up my desire for optimization, I think your advice will help me not to waste time.
Let me think about it a little more.
Thank you so much for the previous and current advice.

#1 Define your dictionary by comprehension :
keys = ['DO1', 'DO2', ...]
cmds = {key: get_data(key) for key in keys}

#2 Yes it exists. This is a cleaner way to populate your dictionary as the key name is redundant. You can modify (statically or dynamically) the keys list to change your dictionary.
#3 Also to have the rest of your code a little bit cleaner, you may want to separate your code into different modules and/or objects.
For example you can create a handler, which methods are the explicit name of your cmds ("cmd1", "cmd2...)
#handler.py
class commandHandler:
    def cmd1(self, pyqt_object, data_string):
        pyqt_object.cmd1_btn.setText(data_string)
    
    def cmd2(self, pyqt_object, data_string):
        pyqt_object.cmd2_drop.setCurrentIndex(int(data_string))

    def cmd3(self, pyqt_object, data_string):
        pass #and so on...

Meanwhile, in your original file, you can use generically this handler with the getattr function :
#your original file
command_handler = commandHandler()
cmds = ['cmd' + str(i) for i in range(1, N+1)] #N being the number of commands
for cmd in cmds:
    if cmd in data:
        getattr(command_handler, cmd)(self, data[cmd])

This way, you have a more generic and reusable code. To add a cmd feature you just have to add a method to your handler.

Why you are passing self while calling the methods? also, I think you forget to create an instance of the commandHandler class to call the methods?

thank you @Lrx for your answer. your idea about cmd name method and getattr looks good.

@Sharim09 The self is because in the original code of simryang (before it was edited and cropped) there was nested if statements within a certain class they used. And indeed you are right, I didn't instantiated the commandHandler, this is fixed now.

You can use the dictionary comprehension to do so:
keys = ["DO1", "DO2", "DO3"]  # Add more keys if you have 
cmds = {key: get_data(key) for key in keys} 

If you just want to save the function (not wanted to call it while the dictionary is creating), you can do that too:
keys = ["DO1", "DO2", "DO3"]  # Add more keys if you have 
cmds = {key: lambda k=key: get_data(k) for key in keys} 


thank you @Sharim09. if any other way does not exists, I'll use that way
